# PowerShell Delete Large SharePoint List item 14 days old

Tags: sharepoint

The script below works for a small sharepoint list but I cannot seem to get it to work with a large list over 700,000 rows.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

````
$list = "Audit Only Test"
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -Fields "Title","Created","ID","ShiftDate"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
   
#Define Query to get list items
$Query= "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
          <Query>
                <Where>
                    <And>
                        <Lt>
                            <FieldRef Name='ShiftDate' Type='DateTime'/>
                            <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>
                                <Today OffsetDays='-7'/>
                            </Value>
                        </Lt>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </And>
                </Where>
            </Query>
         <RowLimit>500</RowLimit>
        </View>"
 
#Get All Items from the List in batches
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $Query -PageSize 500

#Write-host "Total Number of Items Found:"$ListItems.count
foreach($item in $listItems)
{
 Write-Host "Deleting Item - $($item.Id)"
 #$item.deleteobject()
 Remove-PnPListItem -List $listName -Identity $item.Id -Force -ErrorAction Stop
 }
 Write-Host -f Green "`nAll List Items Deleted Successfully!"   ```
````

Comment: If you're doing row deletes, I would recommend that you only retrieve the columns actually needed to match the filter and do the delete.  In your example's case, it would be the ID field for the delete and the ShiftDate field for the filter thus:

`$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -Fields "ID","ShiftDate"`

Comment: With 700,000 items in the list, I would hope that the ShiftDate had an index declared before exceeding 5,000 items otherwise the performance would be extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below command to delete the items:

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $Query -PageSize 500 -ScriptBlock { Param($items)} | % { Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $_.Id -Force}
```

Update:

You don't have to use for each loop through the items, just use the code like the following would work for you:

````
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin   
#Define Query to get list items
$Query= "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
          <Query>
                <Where>
                    <And>
                        <Lt>
                            <FieldRef Name='ShiftDate' Type='DateTime'/>
                            <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>
                                <Today OffsetDays='-7'/>
                            </Value>
                        </Lt>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </And>
                </Where>
            </Query>
         <RowLimit>500</RowLimit>
        </View>"
$ListName="Yourlist name"
Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $Query -PageSize 10 -ScriptBlock { Param($items)} | % {
Write-Host "Deleting Item - $($_.Id)"
 Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $_.Id -Force}   
 Write-Host -f Green "`nAll List Items Deleted Successfully!"   ```
````

Comment: Looks like it is still only running once and not looping through the entire list.  Updated code added after query: 
```#Write-host "Total Number of Items Found:"$ListItems.count
foreach($item in $listItems)
{
 Write-Host "Deleting Item - $($item.Id)"
 #$item.deleteobject()
 Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $Query -PageSize 500 -ScriptBlock { Param($items)} | % { Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $_.Id -Force}
 }
 Write-Host -f Green "`nAll List Items Deleted Successfully!" ```

Comment: You don't have to use the foreach to loop through the entire list. Please check my updated answer. Just use the code like that would work for you.